# Run two variable loop to increment the column number for diff. sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run this in loop by taking two variables for example i and j. Suppose i for sheet 1 and 2 and j for Sheet 3 until I dont reach the end column of sheet 1 or 2.

```
Sub CopyColumn()
'
' CopyColumn Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Columns("B:B").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Columns("D:D").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Columns("E:E").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Columns("F:F").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

I want to run this in loop by taking two variables for example i and j. Suppose i for sheet 1 and 2 and j for Sheet 3 until I dont reach the end column of sheet 1 or 2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try two loops

```
    Sub CopyColumn()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim dest As Worksheet, i, j
    Dim L1 As Long, L2 As Long
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set dest = Sheets("Sheet3")

    With sh1
        L1 = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    End With
    With sh2
        L2 = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    End With
    With dest
        x = 0
        For i = 1 To L1
            sh1.Columns(i).Copy .Cells(1, 1 + x)
            x = x + 2
        Next i
        x = 0
        For j = 1 To L2
            sh2.Columns(j).Copy .Cells(1, 2 + x)
            x = x + 2
        Next j
    End With
   
End Sub
```